# Get numbers from array string representation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this following string:

```
['53456.0','76876.0','456345.0']
```

I have succeded with regex to match just the Elements before commas like:

- `'53456.0'`
- `'76876.0'`
- `'456345.0'`

But what I really Need is to match the numbers without Apostrophe and just the numbers before the Point:

- `53456`
- `76876`
- `456345`

Could you help me to find the approperiate Regular Expression.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A simple `\d+` may help or `\d+(?=\.)`

Comment: try using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) it is much faster than regex and do what I understand you want

Comment: Do you have a string containing all that text from `[` to `]`, or an array containing 3 strings? Please be specific!

Comment: thank you very much. \d+(?=\.) is working just fine

Comment: @PeterB OP is matching `'53456.0'` (watch single quotes). So as they say it is probably of type string.

Comment: Acutally the whole array is a string

Answer (score 2):

You can get the numbers by using a character class that contains the digits 0-9 and the dot character, and then use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get numbers from the strings.

```
[0-9.]+
```

```js
let str = "['53456.0','76876.0','456345.0']";

let numbersAsStrings = str.match(/[0-9.]+/g);

console.log(numbersAsStrings)

let numbers = numbersAsStrings.map(parseFloat);

console.log(numbers)
```

Comment: Yes, or just `.map(parseFloat)` :)

Comment: Thanks! Saving me some bytes here ^^

Comment: And adding some elegance as well :)